# How do I replace button with user uploaded photo

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can't seem to find what I'm missing to replace the button once the user has selected the photo.  Im able to get to the photo selection but once I pick the photo the button still remains the same.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

class profileViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseButton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func btnClicked() {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

        imageView.image = image
    }

    @IBAction func imgUpload(_ sender: Any) {        
        btnClicked()
    }    

    @IBAction func imgUpload2(_ sender: Any) {        
        btnClicked()
    }    

    @IBAction func imgUpload3(_ sender: Any) {        
        btnClicked()
    }

    @IBAction func imgUpload4(_ sender: Any) {        
        btnClicked()
    }

    @IBAction func uploadImgs(_ sender: Any) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the UI?

Comment: where do you want to place the selected image? in the imageView or chooseButton?

Comment: You didn't call `chooseButton` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
//in viewDidLoad() chooseButton.isHidden = false and imageView.isHidden = true

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

    })
    imageView.isHidden = false
    imageView.image = image
    chooseButton.isHidden = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points

1. The image setting is happening after dismissing the UIImagePickerView. Just change the oder and it might work.
2. Instead of

`didFinishPickingImage`

use

`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Following is the implementation of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` that might help you:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){

        var newImage: UIImage

        if let possibleImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
        } else if let possibleImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            newImage = possibleImage
        } else {
            return
        }

        imageView.image = image
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```